# Wine programs disappearing as soon as they're open

Tags: wine, minimize

I have a couple of programs installed using Wine 1.7 and when I open them, they open up and run in the background OK. As soon as I click on them to actually go into it, they immediately get minimised, and I can press the ubuntu (windows) button on my laptop to see the programs, in there I can see my program so again I click on it and it again disappears.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you make screenshots or better yet a short screencast to illustrate the situation?